# Can I retrieve all profile pictures of size "X" for a list of consumers in a single read in Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have the following Blob storage file structure:

```
ConsumerDocs
    Consumer1
        ProfilePictures
            sm
            md
            lg
            xl
        Pdfs
            pdf1
            pdf2
    Consumer2
        ProfilePictures
            sm
            md
            lg
            xl
        Pdfs
            pdf1
            pdf2
    Consumer3
        ProfilePictures
            sm
            md
            lg
            xl
        Pdfs
            pdf1
            pdf2
```

Is there a way in which I can retrieve all of the small profile pictures for a list of consumers using the Azure Blob Storage .NET SDK?

I've tried using GetBlobsAsync(prefix: "folder1/folder2/...")

Thanks

Comment: If you could reorganize the folder structure to ConsumerDocs/ProfilePictures/{size}/ConsumerN you could then use a prefix for the search like "ConsumerDocs/ProfilePictures/sm". Of course that would be for all consumers, not just some list.

Comment: @juunas Unfortunately, I need to keep this structure as retrieving all data for a specific customer is a use case for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not a feature the SDK supports, and we are not planning to support.

The .NET data plane storage SDK calls into the Storage REST APIs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/

It is possible to [list blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs?tabs=azure-ad) and [download blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob), but not in the same REST call.

I recommend calling BlobContainerClient.GetBlobsAync()/GetBobsByHeirarchyAsync() and BlobClient.DownloadAsync() as a work around.